# ArrayList in Scala with Gistlabs Mechanize. Unable to use foreach

Tags: scala, arraylist, mechanize

I'm trying to use [Gistlabs Mechanize](https://github.com/GistLabs/mechanize) to do some web page processing using Scala. I've been able to figure out quite some stuff despite the fact that there is little documentation. Thankfully, there is source.

Snippets that work:

```
val agent= new MechanizeAgent()
agent.setUserAgent(userAgent)

val response:AbstractDocument= form.submit()
```

So, now I want to read through all of the cookies, so I do this. But, first let's the cookies and the class:

```
val cookieStore = response.getAgent().cookies().getAll()
println(cookieStore.getClass())
```

and I get this response:

```
class java.util.ArrayList
```

so, cookieStore is an ArrayList and I should be able to use foreach() with it, right?

When I actually try to do that:

```
cookieStore.foreach { println }
```

I get this error:

```
value foreach is not a member of java.util.List[com.gistlabs.mechanize.cookie.Cookie]
```

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong with Scala, but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.util.List` has not method `foreach`. But you can convert it to scala list using implicit conversion. Just add `import scala.collection.convert.wrapAsScala._` to your source file.